# Compile proftpd with MySQL authentication support on AIX

Tags: compiling, mysql, aix, gcc, xlc

#### Edit 1:

The problem seems to be related to MySQL component. because if I remove every SQL directives from config file, it does work on `ftp/ftpes`, `sftp` and `ftps`

---

#### Edit 2:

If I put an existing host not hosting a DB, connection to ftp daemon will hang and finally timeout, while if I put an incorrect db or a non responding host, it will try to run unix auth instaed of mysql auth.

---

#### Edit 3:

Sqllog mention we can see that the line `Feb 07 15:44:12 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: entering         mysql cmd_open` is followed by a new log line after more than one minute `Feb 07 15:45:27` :

```
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: defaulting to 'mysql' backend
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: backend module 'mod_sql_mysql/4.0.8'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: backend api    'mod_sql_api_v1'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: >>> sql_sess_init
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: entering         mysql cmd_defineconnection
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:   name: 'default'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:   user: 'mysql_poney_user'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:   host: 'pingableHostWithoutDB.net'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:     db: 'mysql_poney_user'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:   port: '15140'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]:    ttl: '2'
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: exiting  mysql cmd_defineconnection
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: connection 'default' successfully established
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: mod_sql engine     : on
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: negative_cache     : off
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: authenticate       : users
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: usertable          : proftpd_users
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: userid field       : userid
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: password field     : passwd
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: UID field          : uid
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: GID field          : gid
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: homedir field      : homedir
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: shell field        : shell
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: SQLMinUserUID      : 200
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: SQLMinUserGID      : 1
Feb 07 15:44:11 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: <<< sql_sess_init
Feb 07 15:44:12 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: >>> sql_escapestr
Feb 07 15:44:12 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: entering         mysql cmd_escapestring
Feb 07 15:44:12 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: entering         mysql cmd_open
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: exiting  mysql cmd_open
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: exiting  mysql cmd_escapestring
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: unrecoverable backend error
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: error: '2003'
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: message: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pingableHostWithoutDB.net' (78)'
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: entering         mysql cmd_exit
Feb 07 15:45:27 mod_sql/4.3[15139036]: exiting  mysql cmd_exit
```

---

#### Orginal question

I have a proftpd config file that is tested on both `proftpd 1.3.4b` and `proftpd 1.3.4d`.  Now I want to compile on a new system a `AIX 6.1`.
I'm using IBM XLc compiler.

here's the library I installed :

```
rpm -qa
    apr-1.4.6-1
    mkisofs-1.13-4
    pci.df1000fa-1-191A5
    openldap-2.4.23-0.3
    apr-util-ldap-1.5.1-1
    openssl-1.0.1e-2
    bash-3.0-1
    coreutils-5.0-2
    grep-2.5.1-1
    pci.1069B166.0A-050A008a-1
    pci.1069B166.08-0508008a-1
    pci.1069B166.10-0510006d-1
    pci.df1000fa-1-90X13
    pci.df1080f9-1-91x4
    ibm.scsi.disk.10k300-RPQR-1
    ibm.scsi.disk.73lpx15-c51d-1
    ibm.scsi.disk.146z10-s28g-1
    ibm.scsi.disk.146lp-C50K-1
    ses.0018-0018-01
    cdrecord-1.9-7
    pci.1069B166.10-0710000b-1
    screen-3.9.10-2
    expat-2.1.0-1
    zlib-1.2.7-2
    AIX-rpm-6.1.6.15-5
    gettext-0.10.40-8
    libiconv-1.14-2
    apr-util-1.5.1-1
    db4-4.7.25-2
    bzip2-1.0.6-1
    info-4.13a-2
    readline-6.2-4
    pcre-8.32-1
    openssl-devel-1.0.1e-2
    httpd-2.4.3-1
    mpfr-3.1.2-1
    MySQL-devel-5.1.56-1
    libgcc-4.6.1-1
    gcc-4.6.1-1
    libstdc++-4.6.1-1
    libstdc++-devel-4.6.1-1
    gmp-5.1.3-1
    gmp-devel-5.1.3-1
    mpfr-devel-3.1.2-1
    libmpc-1.0.1-2
    libmpc-devel-1.0.1-2
    gcc-cpp-4.6.1-1
    zlib-devel-1.2.7-2
```

Here's the script I use to compile:

```
export CONFIG_SHELL=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CONFIG_ENV_ARGS=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CC=cc
export CFLAGS="-qmaxmem=16384 -DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_AIX52 -D_AIX53 -D_AIX61 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"
export CXX=xlC
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export CPPFLAGS='-U__STR__'
export F77=xlf
export FFLAGS="-O -I/opt/freeware/include"
export LD=ld
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/freeware/lib -Wl,-blibpath:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql"
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/opt/perl5/bin:/opt/freeware/bin:/opt/freeware/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/instl
export CFLAGS="-DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_AIX52 -D_AIX53 -D_AIX61 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"
make clean
./configure  '--with-modules=mod_tls:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_sql' '--without-getopt' '--enable-openssl' '--with-includes=/home/poney/libmath_header:/home/poney/include_mysql/mysql/' '--with-libraries=/home/poney/libmath_lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql/libmysqlclient.a' '--prefix=/usr/local/proftpd'
make
```

The things is it does compile without much further warning.  still I do get a warning when `make install`:

```
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .bcopy
ld: 0711-224 WARNING: Duplicate symbol: .memmove
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

My configuration allow FTPS SFTP and FTP, and if I try to connect with `ftps` it does work until I type the password :

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:210 -starttls ftp
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
    verify return:1
    depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    verify return:1
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
       i:/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    ---
    Server certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIICWDCCAcGgAwIBAg[...]8dqCxa3HS6bgg==
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    subject=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    issuer=/C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 1264 bytes and written 341 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Server public key is 1024 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1
        Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
        Session-ID: 6F520DFBC97CF172B68A99510AAFA765658324A4478D87ACB481362070A88034
        Session-ID-ctx:
        Master-Key: [...]
        Key-Arg   : None
        Start Time: 1391443369
        Timeout   : 300 (sec)
        Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
    ---
    220 ProFTPD 1.3.4d Server (ftp daemon) [127.0.0.1]
    USER frank
    331 Password required for frank
    PASS $$$$$
```

And after that nothing, it hangs doing nothing. on the proftpd side the deamon does provide some trace :
[see pastbin](http://pastebin.com/tn51HfSk)

I can't read anything usefull here.

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the library, but I really don't know what or why it does not want to wrok in the end as it compile without problem.

Comment: Don't you need `mod_auth_pam`? AIX uses [PAM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixpluggable/)

Comment: Nope, it is already include in the core of profond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally the answer is:
`It's not a bug it's a feature`

If you try to connect a db that is known in you dns but packets are drop by a firewall, then you fall in the sql timeout of the client (approx 85 sec) and no other authentication works if you have set `AUthOrder` with `mod_sql.c` first.

So my compilation option are correct and package version also.